# Powershell launch exe networkshare switch issue

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, executable

We are trying to launch exe's from a network share.  If we remove all of the switches it will launch the exe's.  If we add switches if does not like the commands.  How do I properly add switches to the exe so it installs correctly?

```
$OSArchCheck = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture
$EMAgent_64 = (Start-Process -Filepath "\\networkshare\Software\Dell\ESSE\Endpoint-Security-Suite-Ent-2.2.0.3\Encryption Management Agent\EMAgent_64bit_setup.exe" -Argumentlist "/s /v FEATURE=BLM CM_EDITION=1 SERVERHOST=esse.domain.com SERVERPORT=8888 SECURITYSERVERHOST=esse.domain.com SECURITYSERVERPORT=8443 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 /norestart /qn") 
#$ATP_64 = (Start-process -filepath "\\networkshare\Software\Dell\ESSE\Endpoint-Security-Suite-Ent-2.2.0.3\AdvancedThreatProtection\WinNtAll\ATP_AgentSetup.exe '/s /norestart REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1'")
#$ATPPlugins_64 = (Start-process -filepath "\\networkshare\Software\Dell\ESSE\Endpoint-Security-Suite-Ent-2.2.0.3\AdvancedThreatProtection\Win64R\ATP_CSF_Plugins_x64.msi '/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress APPFOLDER=C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Advanced Threat Prevention\Plugins ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1'")
#$RemoveItem = (Start-process -filepath "Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Dell Data Security Console.lnk"
#$ATP_86 = (Start-process -filepath "\\networkshare\Software\Dell\ESSE\Endpoint-Security-Suite-Ent-2.2.0.3\AdvancedThreatProtection\WinNtR\ATP_CSF_Plugins_x86.msi '/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress APPFOLDER=C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data Protection\Advanced Threat Prevention\Plugins ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1'")
#$EMAgent_86 = (Start-process -filepath "\\networkshare\Software\Dell\ESSE\Endpoint-Security-Suite-Ent-2.2.0.3\Encryption Management Agent\EMAgent_32bit_setup.exe '/s /v FEATURE=BASIC CM_EDITION=1 SERVERHOST=esseagent.domain.com SERVERPORT=8888 SECURITYSERVERHOST=esseagent.domain.com SECURITYSERVERPORT=8443 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 /norestart /qn'")


If ($OSArchCheck -eq "64-bit") { 

"$EMAgent_64"
"$ATP_64"
"$ATPPlugins_64"
"$RemoveItem"

} Else {

"$EMAgent_86"
"$ATP_86"
"$RemoveItem"

}
```

This is the error I get:

> Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Argumentlist'. At C:\Users\002800\Desktop\powershell esse.ps1:11 char:164 + ... tion Management Agent\EMAgent_64bit_setup.exe" -Argumentlist "/s /v ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

I did find that I had a spelling error for `-Argumentlist`. I am now testing this portion now.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not like the commands"? what are the errors you get?

Comment: Start-Process : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Arguementlist'.
At C:\Users\002800\Desktop\powershell esse.ps1:11 char:164
+ ... tion Management Agent\EMAgent_64bit_setup.exe" -Arguementlist "/s /v  ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: If I drop the "-Arguementlist" and just have the switches in place, it will launch the exe, but it doesn't apply the switches.

Comment: please, add that info to your OP so that everyone can be working from the same data. [*grin*]

Comment: What is the result of the command `Get-Command Start-Process`? To my knowledge `Start-Process` has always contained the `ArgumentList` parameter across all parameter sets so it may be the case that another function with the same name might be called instead of the expected `Start-Process` cmdlet.

Comment: If I move the file locally and run the install through the command line with the switches, it runs an unattended install without any problem.  I'm not sure how to include the switches in powershell and still have it successfully complete the unattended install.